# How can I loop a web.config section and render to HTML in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, runatserver

Say in web.config, I have

```
<configSections>
    <section name="myOptions" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</configSections>

<myOptions>
    <add key="myKey1" value="myValue1">
    <add key="myKey2" value="myValue2">
    ...
</myOptions>
```

I want to loop through `myOptions` and render as HTML using the `key` and `value` fields.

```
<select>
    <option value="myKey1">myValue1</option>
    <option value="myKey2">myValue2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

From Googling, I have tried

```
<% var optionValuePairs = (NameValueCollection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("fundGroupOptions"); %>
<% foreach(string key in optionValuePairs) { %>
   <option value="<% key.ToString(); %>"><% optionValuePairs[key].ToString(); %></option>
<% }; %>
```

I can access the collection just fine.  But my `option value=""` is blank, the `option` text is also blank.

Comment: You will need some sort of looping mechanism, such as a Repeater or GridView, or possibly a plain for loop.

Comment: Thanks.  How can I access web.config and put the section in a key-value collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... I hope this helps someone save time Googling. Web.Config needs to be formatted as above.

Then you just need to access the section as a simple `NameValueCollection`.  You can then use `foreach` to render your HTML.

```
<% var optionValuePairs = (NameValueCollection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("myOptions"); %>
<% foreach(string key in optionValuePairs) { %>
    <option value="<% =key %>"><% =optionValuePairs[key] %></option>
<% }; %>
```